# Can I use the Pi to record and upload video files?

Tags: video

my school has a lot of lectures, and a lot of my classmates miss them. None of them are recorded and you can't access all the information in a central place. As a solution to this, I was wondering if I could build a small computer (preferably a Pi) that records the class with an external camera, and uploads the final video to a Youtube channel, so my classmates that missed the lectures can view them. I just want to set it up in the back and have it do its job.

So a quick summary: 
Can I build a computer/Pi that:
- Records video (with audio)
- Uploads said video to Youtube (or another video sharing site)
(-) Does these things without (too much) user interaction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are allowed to record all the persons with there permission it exist a way to do this, you can use a normal IP cam for this, the Pi can then enter the Stream of the cam via RTSP protocol, you can use the Pi to pipe them into a file.

I think a easy way are 2 buttons added to the Pi via GPIO, this dont need much user interaction, first button to start and stop a record, the second button to upload the video files. A python script can handle the complete control, it means buttons, commands, record, upload.

Maybe a add an LED to the GPIO to display the record status.